# How to pick up passengers by capacity? (ANYLOGİC)

Tags: simulation, anylogic

While picking up, I want to get as many passengers as the bus capacity, and I have to drop a certain amount of passengers in the drop off, but in the scenario I do, it takes it all and leaves it all.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdBq8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pick up all the passengers you want up to the bus capacity, you need to define the pick up block as follows (assuming that the bus agent has a variable or parameter called capacity that defines the capacity of the bus, and if you don't have that variable you need to create it)
[image: pick up block]

You can define your quantity as `agent.capacity-container.contents().size()`
This means that the pick up will take either the maximum it can take, or whatever amount of passengers there are waiting

If you want to fill the bus waiting for passengers until you have the bus full:
[image: pick up block 2]

The dropoff has similar conditions you can use to define how many passengers to drop off... You need to explore that yourself depending on what you want.

Comment: thank you for  your answer , I understood what you mean. Since I was new to anylogic, I did not know how to write blocks. you have been very helpful, thanks